# Laravel 5.5.* directory structure different

Tags: php, laravel

I just created a laravel project using `composer create-project` command from Laravel 5.5 documentation guide.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.5.*"
```

It installed Laravel v5.5.28

When I opened **App** directory it is missing following directories.

- Broadcasting
- Events
- Jobs
- Listeners
- Mail
- Notifications
- Policies
- Providers
- Rules

and many things are different then documentation.
Please guide me in this.

Comment: You can create the folders yourself with the appropriate namespaces for the classes. In fact you can create any folder as long as the classes in that folder have proper namespaces. Hell, you don't even have to use the `App` directory if you don't really want to.

Comment: @Andrew So, It doesn't matter if the folder structure is not same as in the guide?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/structure

Comment: Yes and no. Some folders don't yet exist but will be created with either appropiate artisan commands or by hand, whichever strikes your fancy. You can not use that folder structure but it's easier. Realistically it's just folders, PHP doesn't change as a language. As long as the namespace is correct and composer knows about it, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These folders will show up when you execute `make` commands with artisan.

e.g.

```
php artisan make:mail TestMail
```

Will generate the Mail folder